# Why are file permissions "delayed" when mounting NTFS drives from WSL?

Tags: permissions, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am mounting a Windows/NTFS drive in WSL:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs F: /mnt/f -o uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=177,dmask=077
```

I then check the permissions of an arbitrary file in the newly mounted filesystem:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/f/abc/file.txt
---------- 1 rene rene 5201 Aug 25  2020 /mnt/f/abc/file.txt
```

Apparently, I have no permissions on this file.

Yet, when I execute the same command a second time, I have read and write permissions, as expected:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/f/abc/file.txt
-rw------- 1 rene rene 5201 Aug 25  2020 /mnt/f/abc/file.txt
```

I don't understand why that is.